# Modifying values in master..sysprocesses [Sybase]

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Is there a way to modify the column **program_name** in table **master..sysprocesses**?

I have found two methods, but both set the name during the creation of the connection:

1. Using parameter **appname** when executing an **isql** command
2. Adding parameter **APP=** in a connection string when opening an ODBC connection.

I am looking for a way to modify it AFTER it has been created.

I tried the following example:

```tsql
    sp_configure "allow updates",1
    go
    
    UPDATE master..sysprocesses
    SET program_name = 'test'
    where hostname = 'server'
    and hostprocess = '23240'
    go
    
    sp_configure "allow updates",0
    go
```

But failed:

```
Could not execute statement.
Table 'sysprocesses' can't be modified.
Sybase error code=270
Severity Level=16, State=1, Transaction State=0
Line 4
You can continue executing or stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes to column `sysprocesses.program_name` are not allowed after its been created.  But there are three columns in sysprocesses which can be changed after creation of the connection

- `sysprocesses.clientname`
- `sysprocesses.clientapplname`
- `sysprocesses.clienthostname`

Exerpt from the [Sybase Infocenter](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01672.1570/html/sec_admin/sec_admin116.htm) website:

### Changing user session information

> The `set` command includes options
> that allow you to assign each client an individual name, host name,
> and application name. This is useful for differentiating among clients
> in a system where many clients connect to Adaptive Server using the
> same name, host name, or application name.
>
> The partial syntax for the `set` command is:
>
> `set [clientname client_name | clienthostname host_name | clientapplname application_name]`
>
> where:
>
> **client_name** – is the name you are assigning the client.
>
> **host_name** – is the name of the host from which the client is
> connecting.
>
> **application_name** – is the application that is connecting to Adaptive
> Server.
>
> These parameters are stored in the `clientname`, `clienthostname`, and
> `clientapplname` columns of the `sysprocesses` table.
>
> For example, if a user logs in to Adaptive Server as *"client1"*, you
> can assign them an individual client name, host name, and application
> name using commands similar to:
>
> `set clientname 'alison'`
>
> `set clienthostname 'money1'`
>
> `set clientapplname 'webserver2'`
>
> .
> .
> .
>
> Use the client’s system process ID to view their connection
> information. For example, if the user *“alison”* described above
> connects with a spid of **13**, issue the following command to view all
> the connection information for this user:
>
> `select * from sysprocesses where spid = 13`
>
> To view the connection information for the current client connection (for example, if the user *“alison”* wanted to view her own connection information), enter:
>
> `select * from sysprocesses where spid = @@spid`